# C# delete space from variable

Tags: c#, string, return-value, immutability

My variable looks like:

```
name = "Lola                                 "; // notice the whitespace
```

How can I delete the whitespace at the end to leave me with just "Lola"?

---

Thank you all, but .Trim() don't work to me.

I read the text from a file, if that is any help.

Comment: If Trim() works for everyone but you, the problem isn't with Trim().

Comment: you can't just say name.trim(), you have to assign it to a variable.  so name = name.trim() will work.

Answer (score 17):

use [`Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim%28VS.71%29.aspx).

```
 string name = "Lola       "
 Console.WriteLine(name.Trim()); // puts out 'Lola'
```

Answer (score 9):

If the space will always be at the end of the string, use:

```
name = name.TrimEnd();
```

If the space may also be at the beginning, then use:

```
name = name.Trim();
```

Answer (score 5):

`Trim` doesn't change the string, it creates a new trimmed copy.  That is why it seems like `name.Trim();` isn't doing anything -- you are throwing away the results.

Instead, use `name = name.Trim();` as [ICR suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872286/c-delete-space-from-variable/2872814#2872814).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `.Trim()`. Note that since strings are immutable, you have to assign the result of the operation:

```
name = "Lola                                 ";
name.Trim();  // Wrong: name will be unchanged
name = name.Trim();  // Correct: name will be trimmed
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out string.Trim()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Trim()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
string.Trim()
```

to remove all spaces from your string;

```
string.TrimEnd()
```

to remove spaces from the end of your string

```
string.TrimStart()
```

to remove spaces from the start of your string

Answer (score 0):

use Trim().
So u can get only "Lola"

Answer (score 0):

Or is this what you meant to do?

```
string name = "Lola ...long space...";
Console.WriteLine(name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf(" ") - 1)); // puts out 'Lola'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to remove all spaces anywhere in the string, you could use `Replace()`

```
string name = "   Lola Marceli    ";
Console.WriteLine(name.Replace(" ", "")); // puts out 'LolaMarceli'
```